# escape single quote for google tracker

Tags: google-analytics, escaping

How do you escape single apostrophes in PHP to make google analytics happy?

The documentation here doesn't cover the case of passing a string with a single apostrophe, such as `John's Store'.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

I do not have full control over the string to insert a slash manually, and would prefer to not have to do that anyway.

I can, however use addslash around the value itself. But I am wondering if there is any other way to handle escaping an apostrophe to make google analytics code happy.

I tried using double quotes, around the desired value, but that just breaks the site by rendering an empty document.

```
$result[] = s

printf("ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {'id': '%s',  'affiliation' : "%s", 'revenue': '%01.2f', 'shipping':'%01.2f', 'tax':'%01.2f' });",
               $order->getIncrementId(),
               addslashes(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName()),  // John's Store
               $order->getGrandTotal(),
               $order->getShippingAmount(),
               $order->getTaxAmount(),
                            $order->getTotalQtyOrdered()
```